# Convert pdf pages to images more than 1000

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, pdf

I could convert the pdf pages into images. if it is less than 50 pages its working fast...
if any pdf large than 1000 pages... it acquires lot of time to complete.
any one can review this code and make it work for large file size...
i have used PdfLibNet dll(will not work in 4.0) in .NET3.5
here is my sample code:

```
public void ConverIMG(string filename)
    {          
        PDFWrapper wrapper = new PDFWrapper();
        wrapper.RenderDPI = Dpi;
        wrapper.LoadPDF(filename);
        int count = wrapper.PageCount;
        for (int i = 1; i <= wrapper.PageCount; i++)
        {
            string fileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"IMG\" + i.ToString() + ".png";
            wrapper.ExportJpg(fileName, i, i, (double)100, 100);
            while (wrapper.IsJpgBusy)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
        }
        wrapper.Dispose();            
    }
```

PS:
we need to split pages and convert to images parallely and we need to get completed status.
[image: number of pages and time consumption]

Comment: Well, yeah. For one: Thread.Sleep(50);? What's with that. If you enter that block once for every one of the 1000 pages, just that will be 50 seconds. Why do you have to do that? PDFWrapper runs in a separate thread?

Comment: Is your Thread.Sleep(50) really needed? Could you lower this to a smaller sleep period? At the moment you are spending 5% of your time suspended.

Comment: if ExportJpg is busy while converting a pdf to images i've declared to wait upto 50 millisec...

Comment: Try lowering it to something like 5ms and see what happens. Do you have a good idea for how long ExportJpg should take?

Comment: its all about pdf page contents and size...

Comment: If a sleep() loop is required at all, dump the pdf component in favour of one with creedence. A component or subsystem that cannot signal completion has no place in modern languages/systems/OS.

Comment: So, when you say: "if it is less than 50 pages its working fast...[larger than 1000 pages is slow]." Define: "fast" and "slow." Does 50 pages take 2.5 seconds and 1000 take 50 seconds? Because that's expected behavior (well, with your sleeps). Or does 50 pages take 10 milliseconds and 50 pages takes 5 minutes?

Comment: Profile the app to find out where the delays are. If they are in the PDFWrapper library there is not much you can do without using multiple wrappers, possibly in different processes.  How does your CPU look when it's in the wait state?

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but I did a benchmark on Atalasoft DotImage (my own company's product) and it can convert the PDF Reference (1236 pages) to a set of jpeg images in 385 seconds on a debug build and runs at pretty much a constant 1/3 s per page for 200 dpi output.  By the way, you're saving the files as jpeg, but you're using a png extension.

Comment: @aquinas i have added a screenshot at last.... it's all depends on the page content size... also i changed the thread. sleep to  Thread.Sleep(1);

Answer (score 1):

If `PDFWrapper` performance degrades for documents bigger then 50 pages it suggests it is not very well written. To overcome this you could do conversion in 50 page batches and recreate `PDFWrapper` after each batch. There is an assumption that `ExportJpg()` gets slower with number of calls and its initial speed does not depend on the size of PDF.

This is only a workaround for apparent problems in `PDFWrapper` and a proper solution would be to use a fixed library. Also I would suggest `Thread.Sleep(1)` if you really need to wait with yielding.

```
public void ConverIMG(string filename)
{
    PDFWrapper wrapper = new PDFWrapper();
    wrapper.RenderDPI = Dpi;
    wrapper.LoadPDF(filename);
    int count = wrapper.PageCount;
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        string fileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"IMG\" + i.ToString() + ".png";
        wrapper.ExportJpg(fileName, i, i, (double) 100, 100);
        while (wrapper.IsJpgBusy)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }

        if (i % 50 == 0)
        {
            wrapper.Dispose();
            wrapper = new PDFWrapper();
            wrapper.RenderDPI = Dpi;
            wrapper.LoadPDF(filename);
        }
    }
    wrapper.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: @maciej.. i didn't understand your code if (count % 50 == 0)
        {
            wrapper.Dispose();
            wrapper = new PDFWrapper();
        } if we initialize new object wrapper = new PDFWrapper(); again we need to load pdf file right? see, i'm looking for parallel processing....

Comment: Correct. Updated the code. Parallel processing is also a good idea but not so quick to implement.